# "Collapsing" data columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

can I please get some help wrangling this messy dataset?

The following reprex describes treatments + start/stop dates for five patients. The columns `Line1`, `Line2`, `Line3` describe the order the treatments were administered (i.e. first treatment, second treatment, etc). However, you can see that the data has been entered such that certain patients don’t have their first treatment in the fist column. For example, ID3's first tx was **TreatmentD**, but it has been entered into `Line3`. To complicate matters, some columns have been skipped altogether between consecutive treatments (e.g. ID4).

```r
original_data <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
        patient_id = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5"),
           Line1_name = c("TreatmentA", NA, NA, NA, NA),
          Line1_start = c("5/5/17", NA, NA, NA, NA),
           Line1_stop = c("18/8/17", NA, NA, NA, NA),
           Line2_name = c("TreatmentF","TreatmentB",
                       NA,"TreatmentB","TreatmentF"),
          Line2_start = c("6/11/18", "6/6/18", NA, "3/9/18", "15/11/18"),
           Line2_stop = c("19/12/18", "12/12/18", NA, "22/2/19", "15/6/19"),
           Line3_name = c("TreatmentC", NA, "TreatmentD", NA, "TreatmentC"),
          Line3_start = c("13/2/19", NA, "24/11/17", NA, "29/6/19"),
           Line3_stop = c("2/4/19", NA, "3/4/18", NA, "15/9/19"),
           Line4_name = c(NA, NA, NA, "TreatmentA", NA),
          Line4_start = c(NA, NA, NA, "22/2/19", NA),
           Line4_stop = c(NA, NA, NA, "8/7/19", NA),
           Line5_name = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "TreatmentE"),
          Line5_start = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "15/1/20"),
           Line5_stop = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "20/5/20")
)
head(original_data)
#>   patient_id Line1_name Line1_start Line1_stop Line2_name Line2_start
#> 1        ID1 TreatmentA      5/5/17    18/8/17 TreatmentF     6/11/18
#> 2        ID2       <NA>        <NA>       <NA> TreatmentB      6/6/18
#> 3        ID3       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>       <NA>        <NA>
#> 4        ID4       <NA>        <NA>       <NA> TreatmentB      3/9/18
#> 5        ID5       <NA>        <NA>       <NA> TreatmentF    15/11/18
#>   Line2_stop Line3_name Line3_start Line3_stop Line4_name Line4_start
#> 1   19/12/18 TreatmentC     13/2/19     2/4/19       <NA>        <NA>
#> 2   12/12/18       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>       <NA>        <NA>
#> 3       <NA> TreatmentD    24/11/17     3/4/18       <NA>        <NA>
#> 4    22/2/19       <NA>        <NA>       <NA> TreatmentA     22/2/19
#> 5    15/6/19 TreatmentC     29/6/19    15/9/19       <NA>        <NA>
#>   Line4_stop Line5_name Line5_start Line5_stop
#> 1       <NA>       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>
#> 2       <NA>       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>
#> 3       <NA>       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>
#> 4     8/7/19       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>
#> 5       <NA> TreatmentE     15/1/20    20/5/20
```

**Question**: is there a way I can “collapse” down the data such that no columns are skipped, and all data is “left-shifted” to the earliest treatment # slot that is empty? I tried the using the `dplyr::coalesce()` function, but while I can coalesce `Line2` into `Line1`, I can’t coalesce `Line3` into `Line2`, because the original `Line2` contents is still present (sorry, bit hard to explain). I feel like it probably is the right function though…

**My goal is to get to this**:

```r
final_data <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
        patient_id = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5"),
           Line1_name = c("TreatmentA", "TreatmentB", "TreatmentD", "TreatmentB", "TreatmentF"),
          Line1_start = c("5/5/17", "6/6/18", "24/11/17", "3/9/18", "15/11/18"),
           Line1_stop = c("18/8/17", "12/12/18", "3/4/18", "22/2/19", "15/6/19"),
           Line2_name = c("TreatmentF",NA,
                       NA,"TreatmentA","TreatmentC"),
          Line2_start = c("6/11/18", NA, NA, "22/2/19", "29/6/19"),
           Line2_stop = c("19/12/18", NA, NA, "8/7/19", "15/9/19"),
           Line3_name = c("TreatmentC", NA, NA, NA, "TreatmentE"),
          Line3_start = c("13/2/19", NA, NA, NA, "15/1/20"),
           Line3_stop = c("2/4/19", NA, NA, NA, "20/5/20"),
           Line4_name = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
          Line4_start = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
           Line4_stop = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
           Line5_name = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
          Line5_start = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
           Line5_stop = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)
head(final_data)
#>   patient_id Line1_name Line1_start Line1_stop Line2_name Line2_start
#> 1        ID1 TreatmentA      5/5/17    18/8/17 TreatmentF     6/11/18
#> 2        ID2 TreatmentB      6/6/18   12/12/18       <NA>        <NA>
#> 3        ID3 TreatmentD    24/11/17     3/4/18       <NA>        <NA>
#> 4        ID4 TreatmentB      3/9/18    22/2/19 TreatmentA     22/2/19
#> 5        ID5 TreatmentF    15/11/18    15/6/19 TreatmentC     29/6/19
#>   Line2_stop Line3_name Line3_start Line3_stop Line4_name Line4_start
#> 1   19/12/18 TreatmentC     13/2/19     2/4/19         NA          NA
#> 2       <NA>       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>         NA          NA
#> 3       <NA>       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>         NA          NA
#> 4     8/7/19       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>         NA          NA
#> 5    15/9/19 TreatmentE     15/1/20    20/5/20         NA          NA
#>   Line4_stop Line5_name Line5_start Line5_stop
#> 1         NA         NA          NA         NA
#> 2         NA         NA          NA         NA
#> 3         NA         NA          NA         NA
#> 4         NA         NA          NA         NA
#> 5         NA         NA          NA         NA
```

Thanks!

Comment: It appears that `dplyr::coalesce()` works fine on my machine. For example: `final_data <-original_data %>% mutate(Line1_name = coalesce(!!!list(a$Line1_name, a$Line2_name, a$Line3_name, a$Line4_name))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question!

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

original_data %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Line"),
               names_sep = "_",
               names_to = c("line", "prop"),
               values_drop_na = T) %>%
  group_by(patient_id) %>%
  mutate(line = as.numeric(factor(line))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(name = sprintf("Line%s_%s", line, prop)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = patient_id, names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

returns:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 10
  patient_id Line1_name Line1_start Line1_stop Line2_name Line2_start Line2_stop
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>       <chr>      <chr>      <chr>       <chr>
1 ID1        TreatmentA 5/5/17      18/8/17    TreatmentF 6/11/18     19/12/18
2 ID2        TreatmentB 6/6/18      12/12/18   NA         NA          NA
3 ID3        TreatmentD 24/11/17    3/4/18     NA         NA          NA
4 ID4        TreatmentB 3/9/18      22/2/19    TreatmentA 22/2/19     8/7/19
5 ID5        TreatmentF 15/11/18    15/6/19    TreatmentC 29/6/19     15/9/19
# … with 3 more variables: Line3_name <chr>, Line3_start <chr>,
#   Line3_stop <chr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shift all the non-NA values to the left -

```
original_data[] <- t(apply(original_data, 1,function(x) na.omit(x)[1:length(x)]))

#  patient_id Line1_name Line1_start Line1_stop Line2_name Line2_start Line2_stop
#1        ID1 TreatmentA      5/5/17    18/8/17 TreatmentF     6/11/18   19/12/18
#2        ID2 TreatmentB      6/6/18   12/12/18       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>
#3        ID3 TreatmentD    24/11/17     3/4/18       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>
#4        ID4 TreatmentB      3/9/18    22/2/19 TreatmentA     22/2/19     8/7/19
#5        ID5 TreatmentF    15/11/18    15/6/19 TreatmentC     29/6/19    15/9/19

#  Line3_name Line3_start Line3_stop Line4_name Line4_start Line4_stop Line5_name
#1 TreatmentC     13/2/19     2/4/19       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
#2       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
#3       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
#4       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
#5 TreatmentE     15/1/20    20/5/20       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>       <NA>

#  Line5_start Line5_stop
#1        <NA>       <NA>
#2        <NA>       <NA>
#3        <NA>       <NA>
#4        <NA>       <NA>
#5        <NA>       <NA>
```